# Error match is not defined no-undef en react.js

Tags: reactjs

A través de `<Route>`, dirijo a distintos componentes. En uno de ellos necesito pasar un parámetro, y lo hago de esta forma:

```
const AppRoutes = () =>

      <Switch>
        <Route path='/:slug' component={Articulo} />
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route component={Page404} />
      </Switch>


export default AppRoutes;
```

El componente `<articulo>` lo he creado en un fichero aparte, pero algo estoy haciendo mal y no sé el qué. El fichero lo tengo así:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Articulo extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<h2>Este es el slug del artículo: {match.params.slug}</h2>)
  }

}

export default Articulo;
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve un error:

> 'match' is not defined  no-undef

Todos la documentación que he encontrado crear el componente en el mismo fichero de esta forma:

```
const Articulo = () => (
  <h1>Este es el slug: {match.params.slug}</h1>
)
```

De esta forma no habría problema, pero necesito hacerlo en un componente separado.

Comment: Las variables de ruta se acceden mediante properties, es decir: this.props.match.params. Deberia ser this.props.match.slug en lugar de match.params.slug

Comment: @MarcosMartínez ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha servido.

Comment: JetLagFox, creo puedes eliminar la pregunta al ser producto de un **error tipográfico**.

Comment: @MarcosMartínez toda propiedad de una clase debe accederse por medio de `this`. En versiones futuras de ECMAScript no será necesario.

Comment: Agradezco la info pero no lo veo relativo a la pregunta del OP. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El componente router de react-router le pasa a tu componente una serie de propiedades, las cuales puedes acceder a ellas desde tu componente de clase como this.props.match, en un componente funcional solo pones props Cómo argumento
const Componente=(props)=>(...)